# Blazor When switching from ServerPrerendered to WebAssemblyPrerendered get error "Found malformed component"

Tags: .net, blazor, webapi

When switching from ServerPrerendered to WebAssemblyPrerendered get error "Found malformed component". How to fix this error?

regards

Comment: Are we dealing with a Blazor Server or Blazor WebAssembly project?

Comment: i Added some custom components but it happened on "hello word default page"

Comment: I ask because you cannot use `ServerPrerendered` with Blazor WebAssemly (see this [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38049)) and also not `WebAssemblyPrerendered` with Blazor Server. You'll have to wait till .NET 8 drops with [Blazor United](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2023/04/20/blazor-net-8.aspx) which supports mixing those rendering modes in a single project or page.